# how to have UIImage below UILabel or UITextView in a scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uilabel

How can I set a `UILabel` or `UITextView`below an `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView` so that when the image is scrolled, the label or text should also scrolled along with it simultaneously. Need guidance on this.

Comment: Use IB for placing imageView below label and textView. Then create a property with IBOutlet and connect it respectively.

Comment: ...Atleast vote up dude !

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow sorry :) i'm not getting u

Comment: just in starting to my comment there's a vote up option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must implement your `UIScrollView` and then add the desired subview (`UIImageView` and `UILabel` in your case).

In you `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, 100)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.size.width, 0, imageView.frame.size.width * 2, 40)];
label.text = @"Hello World";

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[scrollView addSubview:label];
```

Do not forget to set your `UIScrollView`'s content size > to your frame:

```
scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

This should provide you the guidance you requested.

Comment: I want to scroll the images Horizontally any suggestions?

Comment: @Satish_225 I edited my answer to your desired scroll type.
Typically, the `setContentSize` is important: you need to understand that it will lead your scroll, if you frame is (10x10) and your `contentSize` (10x20), so your scroll will be horizontal